# php artisan migrate issue

Tags: php, laravel

when I tried to do `php artisan migrate` this error appeared

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
> (SQL: create table `migrations` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment prim
> ary key, `migration` varchar(255) not null, `batch` int not null) default charac
> ter set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

I searched but all the results are talking about the command `php artisan serve`

Comment: If you're using a socket file to connect to the database make sure it's readable by the current user

Comment: I gave it the everyone permission but it still not working

Comment: Have you updated the correct database details in .env file?

Comment: I updated the .env file so that the database will run in local host and set the user name and password too

Comment: It turns out that my antivirus was blocking the access